# How to track pdf downloads with Google Analytics

Tags: pdf, google-analytics

I wouldn't track pdf downloads as an event, but as a virtual page view.

GA has a [resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) about Tracking virtual pageviews.

I have a CMS and I don't understand how to implement this solution.

For ex. how could I insert this string of GA code

```
ga('set', 'page', '/new-page.html');
```

inserting the url of every pdf to download instead of /new-page.html?

Comment: Do you want trigger a virtual pageview if someony click a download link?

Comment: that's correct @MFGSparka

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to send a pageview hit on click event on your pdf link or button and provide distinct value for a 'page' parameter. Use ga('send') to actually send data to Analytics. There are multiple ways to pass the parameters, learn more at [page tracking guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages). Consider a clicked element is an `a` with `#pdfLink` id:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("pdfLink").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
    ga('send', 'pageview', this.href);

  }, false);
</script>
```

In this example, a click on an element with #pdfLink Id will populate a pageview in Analytics for a page named as the link to pdf file.