# Google Analytics Events Don't Appear to be Working

Tags: html, web, google-analytics, tracking

I currently have Google Analytics added to my webpage and I'm trying to add some events such as files downloaded, buttons clicked, etc.. nothing too complicated. I feel like I must be missing something very obvious, because everything have tried so far has resulted in being able to see the users viewing the website but 0 events showing up on the Google Analytics dashboard. I am entirely self taught and have looked at other questions and answers such as the following:

[Google Analytics tracking code doesn't record downloads in RealTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52048136/google-analytics-tracking-code-doesnt-record-downloads-in-realtime)

and

[How to track pdf downloads with Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285513/how-to-track-pdf-downloads-with-google-analytics)

I am using the following in my header with the ID# replaced with X's:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

With the following attempts, with respect to the linked questions:

1st question linked:

```
<a href="/downloads/Test.pdf" onclick = "gtag('send', 'event', {'event_category': 'download','event_label': 'download_clicked'});">Click here to download a PDF.</a>
```

2nd question linked:

```
<script>
var trackDownload = function(url) {
   gtag('send', 'event', 'download', 'download_clicked', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>

<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/downloads/Test.pdf" onclick="trackDownload('http://www.mywebsite.com/downloads/Test.pdf'); return false;">Click here to download a PDF.</a>
```

What am I missing? Any help is very appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing syntax of `ga` and `gtag`.

Syntax to send event with gtag is the following:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

So to send your event you have to use this code:

```
gtag('event', 'download_clicked', { event_category: 'download' });
```

Where *download_clicked* is action (category and action are mandatory).

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! I feel so silly having spent a couple hours on that all due to a mix up of syntax. Sometimes you just need a pair of fresh (and more experienced) eyes.